# Handshake inactivity timeout error when connecting node v5.10.1. to aws mysql RDS

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, rds

Im having a really hard to time solving this issue.  When I try to connect node to aws's rds mysql database, I receive this error:

```
{ [Error: Handshake inactivity timeout]
  code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: 10000 }
```

Solutions online suggest updating to node v4.2.1 but I am on v5.10.1.
I have no problems when I connect node to my localhost mysql.

Here is my code:

```
connectionpool = mysql.createPool({
        host     : 'dev-db.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        user     : 'xxxxx',
        password : 'xxxxx',
        database : 'decurate',

    });

app.get('/:table', function(req,res){
connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('CONNECTION error: ',err);
            res.statusCode = 503;
              res.send({
                result: 'error',
                err:    err.code
            });
        } else {

           connection.query('SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 20', req.params.id, function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    res.statusCode = 500;
                    res.send({
                        result: 'error',
                        err:    err.code
                    });
                }


                res.send({
                    result: 'success',
                    err:    '',
                    json:   rows
                });
                connection.release();
            });
        }
    });


});
```

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try connecting to the server from the node machine using the mysql command line client... or using `nc` or even `telnet` -- something to verify simple network connectivity?

Comment: yeah it works fine if i connect to mysql server via SSH or MSQL workbench. `just not working in node.

Comment: Okay, but *from the machine running node* does the command `nc dev-db.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3306` return the expected garbage-looking string, like `N
5.6.19-logxxxwRrf,FZpxxxHUQx)a-[ca?Rmysql_native_password`?  Or `telnet dev-db.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3306` Or even `cat < /dev/tcp/dev-db.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/3306`?  Any of those things can be used to test connectivity.

Comment: I tried the `nc dev-db.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3306` command and this is the response that I received `nc: connect to dev-db.xxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com port 3306 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out`

Comment: OMG!! After days of headache, I figured it out. I had my aws ec2 instance security group receiving traffic from my ip rather than the ec2 ip. PRAISE THE LORD!! Thank you so much for your help @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with the host that cannot connect to mysql db. I solved this by adding host configuration to my hosts file. Even if any aws instance you running, you should configure your domain name to hosts file. So that in your application configuration automatically lookup to desired IP Address.

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.0.1     yourdomain.com
```

Restart your apache.

It works for me. Try this & let me know.